# Pause JS slideshow after X slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to play around with a JS plugin I found on Codrops:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/

I'm trying to get the slideshow to auto stop after X images. In my case 2 or 3. From what I understood of Mary Lou's code, the function to determine pause/play/next slide is here:

```
function d(q) {
    var p = g.eq(h);
    console.log('abc');
    if (q === "next") {
        h = h < n - 1 ? ++h : 0
    } else {
        if (q === "prev") {
            h = h > 0 ? --h : n - 1
        }
    }
    var o = g.eq(h);
    p.css("opacity", 0);
    o.css("opacity", 1)
}
```

This JS is found here:

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/BackgroundSlideshow/js/cbpBGSlideshow.js

What I've tried till now is basically place break points in the code to see what happens where and this is the conclusion I've come to.

Any help figuring out the rest of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Stop after X images or at a certain image? What if users press the back button?

Comment: No, in my playground, I've removed the three play, pause, next buttons from the HTML code.

Comment: Try `if(h !== 3) { p.css("opacity", 0);
    o.css("opacity", 1); }`

Comment: That didn't work when put after or before the `if` statements

Comment: It should go instead of the `p.css` and `o.css` lines

Comment: I posted an answer so you can mark this question as answered (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement to not do prevent the `.css` commands from being reached. The following should stop it on the third slide

```
function d(q) {
    var p = g.eq(h);
    console.log('abc');
    if (q === "next") {
        h = h < n - 1 ? ++h : 0
    } else {
        if (q === "prev") {
            h = h > 0 ? --h : n - 1
        }
    }
    var o = g.eq(h);
    if(h !== 3) { 
        p.css("opacity", 0); 
        o.css("opacity", 1); 
    }
}
```

With this being said, I'd recommend stopping whatever is firing that function in the if statement instead. That way it's not running this function when it's not doing something